# How to retrieve a friendlist's members count with Graph Api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to retrieve a friendlist's members count. But Get("me/friendlists") returns only friendlist's id,name and list_type.

```
_currentFbClient = new FacebookClient(_userToken);
_me = _currentFbClient.Get("me/friendlists");
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a count available, you've to pull the members list of each group and count them yourself unfortunately

You can get the members of a list with a GET to `/FRIEND_LIST_ID/members`

Once you have the friend list IDs, put them into a string, comma separated, and you can get a full list of members of all the lists in a single call by calling

`_currentFbClient.Get("/?fields=members&ids=$STRING_CONTAINING_IDS_OF_LISTS")`

The response will be something like this:

```
{
 "LIST_ID_1": {
    "members": {
      "data": [
        {     {
          "id": "USER ID", 
          "name": "NAME"
        }, 
        // Other friends on list
     }
  },
  "LIST_ID_2:{
// etc etc
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know `_currentFbClient.Get("/?fields=members&ids=$STRING_CONTAINING_IDS_OF_LISTS")` was possible!!  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I thought /FRIEND_LIST_ID/members limited 25. But it contains all friends in the list. Thank you.

Comment: @DMCS yeah it's not a pattern a lot of people seem to use, but can be very useful when you have multiple objects and want some fields of those objects in a single call